# Utilizing change event with select in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select named states with the 50 states as options (generated via php). I'd like to trigger an event if a certain state is selected.  Here is my test code that doesn't seem to be working

```
$("#states").on('change', function () {
    var stateSelect = $("#states").val();
    if (stateSelect == "Canada") {
        alert("Test!"); //code
    }
});
```

thanks

Comment: for the time being consider canada a state lol

Comment: _doesn't seem to be working_ ? Any error ?

Comment: It's working for me - http://jsfiddle.net/QJyDE/

Comment: You must have an error somewhere else in your JS; your code is valid - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/ee3HH/1/)

Comment: of course you are waiting for DOM ready, right? And of course #states is an unique/static element, still right?

Comment: I had an error elsewhere. thanks for the help.  checking answer below, so question i solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should look like this

```
$("#states").change(function(e) { var selectedValue = $(this).val(); });
```

This will return the selectedValue.